# Where can I get a text (or database) copy of the .net 3.5 Object Hierachy

Tags: c#, .net

When you open up Visual Studio and select View - Object Browser, you get a list of all objects in the .net framework:  Assemblies - Namespaces - Classes - Methods and attributes.

I want create a database that contains this information. Does anyone know where I could get a copy of this data in a text or database format?

Comment: just curious: why on earth would you want to do this when there's already http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229335.aspx ?

Comment: Not to mention the fact that it changes, and why on earth would you want to worry about keeping it up-to-date when Microsoft does it for you... And doesn't the MSDN library come with Visual Studio already?  (Does it come with express versions?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection to loop through the types and members in each assembly and dump it to XML or a relational database.

To find the assemblies, loop through all of the DLL files in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727` and `C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework` and call `Assembly.FromFile`.  Note that some of the DLLs are unmanaged, so you'll need a `catch` block.

Each of the managed DLLs will have a corresponding XML file with the same name containing the IntelliSense documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You could use intellisense XML files, which visual studio uses to show classes/members etc.
I am sorry, I don't know where the file(s) is located.